# Is it possible to make permission changes to a read only file system in linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions, qemu, read-only

I have a compressed rom file system, to which I require some permission changes to be made.

```
rootfs: Linux Compressed ROM File System data, little endian size 7360512 version #2 sorted_dirs CRC 0xa71a1ac3, edition 0, 4279 blocks, 942 files
```

It is a root file system with basic directories like bin, sbin, etc, ...
I require certain permission changes to be made in the etc directory to get the system to boot on QEMU.

I have tried to mount the file system with read write privileges but I only get the following:

```
mount: warning: tmp seems to be mounted read-only.
```

This is the command I am using:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw -t cramfs rootfs tmp
```

Comment: You will likely have to provide more information. What are you trying to mount and what are the mount options you are trying (your exact mount command) ?

Comment: I have added some more information, I hope it is helpful

Comment: That was indeed very helpful :)

Comment: You could also work around the permissions issue by mounting `tmp` as a `tmpfs` on boot, but without knowing more about what's booting, I'm unsure as to how you would do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The filesystem you have is cramfs. That filesystem can't be made read/write.

You will most likely need to extract the filesystem, modify it, and build a new cramfs image. I've not played around with it, but the steps would be something along the lines of:

1. create a directory on a read/write filesystem.
2. copy the files from the cramfs filesystem to that directory.
3. modify the data in the created directory
4. use a tool like mkcramfs on given directory to make a new compressed image
5. replace the cramfs file device with the newly created one.

Comment: Are there any suggested tools that I can use for extraction? I have tried binwalk, but for some reason, that does not extract all the directories.

Comment: Mount it read-only, then use something like `rsync` , or even the ancient `cpio -p` on it.

Comment: ```rsync``` worked, thank you much!